# How can I create a 2 dimensional array on Heap in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to make a chess simulation in C++. I have created a class Pieces and I want to create a 2 dimensional array on heap consisting of all Pieces. This is my code : king, queen and others derive from Pieces.

```
king = new King();
queen = new Queen();
knight = new Knight();
bishop = new Bishop();
rook = new Rook();
pawn = new Pawn();
empty = new Pieces();

Pieces* startup[64] = {rook, knight, bishop, king, queen, bishop, knight, rook,
                       pawn, pawn, pawn, pawn, pawn, pawn, pawn, pawn,
                       empty, empty, empty, empty, empty, empty, empty, empty,
                       empty, empty, empty, empty, empty, empty, empty, empty,
                       empty, empty, empty, empty, empty, empty, empty, empty,
                       empty, empty, empty, empty, empty, empty, empty, empty,
                       pawn, pawn, pawn, pawn, pawn, pawn, pawn, pawn,
                       rook, knight, bishop, king, queen, bishop, knight, rook};
Pieces* board = new Pieces[8][8];
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        board[i][j] = startup[k];
        k++;
    }
}
```

But this gives me the following errors :

```
ChessBoard.cpp: In constructor ‘ChessBoard::ChessBoard()’:
ChessBoard.cpp:25: error: cannot convert ‘Pieces (*)[8]’ to ‘Pieces*’ in initialization
ChessBoard.cpp:29: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘board[i][j]’
```

How can I successfully allocate a 2 dimensional array on heap ?
And also what is better to create an array of Pointers to Pieces or creating an array of Pieces Objects ?

Comment: You're missing another `*` for the type of `board`, but why would you have a heap chess board? Use `std::array<std::array<Pieces, 8>, 8>`. You don't need dynamic allocation for a fixed-size, even compile-time fixed-size 2D array.

Comment: `new Pieces[8][8]` gives you a `Pieces (*)[8]` (which is a pointer to an array of 8 `Pieces`), not a `Pieces*`.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need all the dynamic allocation? Simply have a 64-element array of enums and layer some faked 2D indexing on top.

Here's an example:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

enum class piece_t
{
   EMPTY = 0, PAWN, ROOK, BISHOP, KNIGHT, QUEEN, KING
};

static const size_t WIDTH = 8, HEIGHT = 8;
struct board_t : std::array<piece_t, WIDTH*HEIGHT>
{
    board_t()
    {
        for (size_t y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
            for (size_t x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
                operator()(x,y) = piece_t::EMPTY;
    }

    piece_t& operator()(size_t x, size_t y)
    {
        return operator[](x + y*WIDTH);
    }

    const piece_t& operator()(size_t x, size_t y) const
    {
        return operator[](x + y*WIDTH);
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const piece_t& piece)
{
    switch (piece) {
        case piece_t::KING:   return (os << 'K');
        case piece_t::QUEEN:  return (os << 'Q');
        case piece_t::KNIGHT: return (os << 'N');
        case piece_t::BISHOP: return (os << 'B');
        case piece_t::ROOK:   return (os << 'R');
        case piece_t::PAWN:   return (os << 'P');
        case piece_t::EMPTY:  return (os << ' ');
        default:              return (os << '?');
    }
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const board_t& board)
{
    os << '+' << std::string(WIDTH, '-') << '+' << '\n';
    for (size_t y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
        os << '|';
        for (size_t x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
            os << board(x, y);
        os << '|' << '\n';
    }
    os << '+' << std::string(WIDTH, '-') << '+' << '\n';
    return os;
}

int main()
{
   board_t b;
   b(3, 5) = piece_t::KING;
   b(6, 4) = piece_t::KNIGHT;
   std::cout << b << std::endl;
   // etc.
}
```

#### [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e3c08a26900f9a4)

So much simpler, and *safer*. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You just need two simple changes. The declaration for board should be:

```
  Pieces (*board)[8]  = new Pieces[8][8];
```

In other words, `board` is a pointer to (an array of) 8-element arrays. Then the assignment should be:

```
  board[i][j] = *startup[k];
```

Note that the board is a 2-dimensional array of Pieces - not an array of pointers, which is perhaps what you really wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Create your board array like this

```
Pieces** board=new Pieces*[8];
for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
{
   board[i] = new Pieces[8];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::array<std::array<Pieces, 8>, 8>` is probably the most succinct way to define your board.

If you can't use std::array, you can allocate a two-dimensional array as one contiguous block first, and then have the two-dimensional pointer point to that buffer, as follows:

```
Pieces * buffer = new Pieces [8 * 8];
Pieces (*board)[4] = reinterpret_cast<Pieces (*)[8]>(buffer);
...
delete [] buffer;
```

This allows you to use the normal two-dimensional indexing without having to go through the extra layer of indirection that would occur when P is of type Pieces **. The syntax is of course the same, but the memory layout is significantly different.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int * buffer = new int [7 * 4];
    for( int i = 0; i < 28; ++i )
        buffer[i] = i;

    int (*P)[4] = reinterpret_cast<int (*)[4]>(buffer);
    for( int i = 0; i < 7; ++i )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < 4; ++j )
            std:: cout << P[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    delete [] buffer;
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 
4 5 6 7 
8 9 10 11 
12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 
24 25 26 27
```

Comment: He should use `Pieces*` in `std::array<std::array<Pieces*, 8>, 8>`, else he will have slicing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following works:

```
Pieces* (*board)[8][8] = new Pieces*[1][8][8];
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        (*board)[i][j] = startup[k];
        k++;
    }
}
```

But `ChessBoard` may have directly a member:

```
Pieces* board[8][8];
```

And so less memory management.

Comment: Wait a minute, is that C++? Can you point me to some document having more information?

Comment: I know that stuff, what I didn't know is that `new` supported multidimensional allocation.

Comment: Isn't that too much? I think that `Pieces (*board)[8] = new Pieces[8][8];` should be enough, you are adding an unnecessary indirection.

Comment: @ichramm: **1.** The extra pointer for `Pieces*` is to avoid slicing. **2.** `new Pieces[8][8]` creates an array of 8 pointers (of type `Pieces (*)[8]`) whereas `new Pieces [1][8][8]` create an array of 1 pointer (of the correct type: `Pieces (*)[8][8]`).